# Prolog program to reverse and append the list

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog. I am trying to reverse the order of list and append them.

For example :

revappend([1,2], [3,4], X) Should give me result like :

X = [3,4,1,2]

The code I wrote :

```
revappend([],List,List).
revappend(InputListB,[Head|InputListA], [Head|OutputList]):-
   revappend( InputListA, InputListB, OutputList).
```

Giving me result like :

X = [15, 11, 16, 12, 13, 14]

Can someone tell me how to do this??

Comment: what's wrong with `revappend(A, B, C) :- append(B, A, C).` ? And for your "Giving me result like..." you didn't say what the inputs were. So that's a bit unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to reverse the order of list and append them or more precisely you want to append second list with the first list and here is prolog rule to do the same.

```
append(List,[],List).
append(List,[Head|Tail],[Head|Res]):-append(List,Tail,Res).
```

The 1st rule says that when the 2nd list is empty you gonna append the first list to the result.

The second rule says that you gonna add head of the second list to the result and recursively  append the tail of the second list with the first list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is unclear to me. If what you want is to have

```
revappend( [1,2] , [3,4] , L ) .
```

produce, as your example shows:

```
L = [3,4,1,2]
```

the solution is easy:

```
revappend( Xs , Ys , Zs ) :- append(Ys,Xs,Zs) .
```

If you don't want to, or can't use, the built-in `append/3`, you might do something like:

```
revappend( [] , [] , [] ) .
revappend( Xs , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs] ) :- revappend( Xs , Ys , Zs ) .
revappend( [X|Xs] , [] , [X|Zs] ) :- revappend( Xs , [] , Zs ) .
```

However, when I hear something like your problem statement, though:

> I am trying to reverse the order of list and append them.

I would expect that your

```
revappend( [1,2] , [3,4] , L ) .
```

would produce either `L = [2,1,4,3]` or `L = [4,3,2,1]`.

For the former (`[2,1,4,3]`) case, you might write something like this:

```
revappend( Xs, Yz , Zs ) :- revappend(Xs,Yz,[],Zs) .

revappend( []     , []     , Zs , Zs ) .
revappend( [X|Xs] , Ys     , Rs , Zs ) :- revappend(Xs,Ys,[X|Rs],Zs).
revappend( []     , [Y|Ys] , Rs , Zs ) :- revappend([],Ys,[Y|Rs],Zs).
```

For the latter (`[4,3,2,1]`), you just need to change things up a bit, modifying `revappend/4` along these lines:

```
revappend( []     , []     , Zs , Zs ) .
revappend( Xs     , [Y|Ys] , Rs , Zs ) :- revappend(Xs,Ys,[Y|Rs],Zs).
revappend( [X|Xs] , []     , Rs , Zs ) :- revappend(Xs,[],[X|Rs],Zs).
```

Note that you can do this with built-ins as well:

```
revappend(Xs,Ys,Zs) :-
  reverse(Xs,X1) ,
  reverse(Ys,Y1) ,
  append(X1,Y1,Zs)
  .
```

Comment: revappend( [X|Xs] , [] , [X|Zs] ) :- revappend( Xs , [] , Zs ) . this rule is not so clear to me. I think this rule explains if the second list is empty then, append second list to first list and get the result of first list and as I am just new learner I explained it by using fact : revappend( [X|Xs] , [] , [X|Xs] ). am I wrong?